# mongo db indexing.. how should I index the collection

Tags: mongodb

This is my dataset

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e86e98f493590878bb4db1"),
    "ZIP" : 37663,
    "ADULTS_M_18_24" : "Y",
    "ADULTS_F_18_24" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_18_24" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_25_34" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_25_34" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_25_34" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_35_44" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_35_44" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_35_44" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_45_54" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_45_54" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_45_54" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_55_64" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_55_64" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_55_64" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_65_74" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_65_74" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_65_74" : "",
    "ADULTS_M_75PLUS" : "",
    "ADULTS_F_75PLUS" : "",
    "ADULTS_U_75PLUS" : ""
}
```

having more than 200000000 records

I need to run this query

```
db.consumer1s.find({$and:[{ZIP:37663},{$or:[{ADULTS_M_18_24:"Y"},{ADULTS_M_25_34:"Y"},{ADULTS_F_25_34:"Y"}]}]})
```

What should my index be ??

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want an index on the `ZIP` field, as this is a useful single field with a fair amount of grouping that you plan to query by. That makes it pretty ideal for indexing.

The rest of the fields are a bit problematic. They almost certainly *shoudln't* be indexed because you'd have to index all of them to get full results, and indexing all of them would make write operations *much* slower. I think what you really want here is a schema redesign. What about something like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e86e98f493590878bb4db1"),
    "ZIP" : 37663,
    "Age" : 35,
    "Gender": "M/F/U"
}
```

This schema is better for 2 reasons:

1. Much more readable without losing any of the information you needed
2. You can make indexes on both `Age` and `Gender` without such an extreme hit

Then you just need to change your query a bit to use `$gt`, `$lt` and possibly `$eq` to get the same result